# Trying to create an efficient algorithm for a function in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, divide-and-conquer

I'm looking for an efficient polynomial-time solution to the following problem:

Implement a recursive function node x y for calculating the (x,y)-th number in a number triangle defined as

```
g(x,y) = 0 if |x| > y
       = 1 if (x,y) = (0,0)
       = sum of all incoming paths otherwise
```

The sum of all incoming paths to a node is defined as the sum of the values of all possible paths from the root node (x, y) = (0, 0) to the node under consideration, where at each node (x,y) a path can either continue diagonally down and left (x−1,y+1), straight down (x,y+1), or diagonally down and right (x+1,y+1). The value of a path to a node is defined as the sum of all the nodes along that path up to, but not including, the node under consideration.

The first few entries in the number triangle are given in the table:

```
\  x  -3  -2  -1  0  1  2  3 
 \  
y \ _________________________
   |
0  |   0   0   0  1  0  0  0
   |
1  |   0   0   1  1  1  0  0
   |
2  |   0   2   4  6  4  2  0
   |
3  |   4   16  40 48 40 16 4
```

I am trying to work out a naive solution first, here is what I have:

```
node x y | y < 0                = error "number cannot be negative"
         | (abs x) > y          = 0
         | (x == 0) && (y == 0) = 1
         | otherwise            = node (x+1) (y-1) + node x (y-1) + node (x-1) (y-1)
```

Whenever I run this I get:

"*** Exception: stack overflow"?

Comment: Note that you can efficiently calculate triangular number with a closed form expression, given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: What you are describing is a generalization of Pascal's triangle. See [this](http://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2852&context=thesesdissertations) paper.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is a bit more complicated than your example code suggests. First, let's be clear about some definitions here:

Let `pathCount x y` be the number of paths that end at (x, y). We have

```
pathCount :: Int -> Int -> Integer
pathCount x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathCount (x + d) (y - 1) | d <- [-1..1]]
```

Now let's `pathSum x y` be the sum of all paths that end in (x, y). We have:

```
pathSum :: Int -> Int -> Integer
pathSum x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathSum (x + d) (y - 1) + node x y * pathCount (x + d) (y - 1)
                     | d <- [-1..1] ]
```

With this helper, we can finally define `node x y` properly:

```
node :: Int -> Int -> Integer
node x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathSum (x + d) (y - 1) | d <- [-1..1]]
```

This algorithm as such is exponential time in its current form. We can however add [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to make the number of additions quadratic. The [`memoize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize) package on Hackage makes this easy as pie. Full example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.Function.Memoize (memoize2)

node' :: Int -> Int -> Integer
node' x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathSum (x + d) (y - 1) | d <- [-1..1]]
node = memoize2 node'

pathCount' :: Int -> Int -> Integer
pathCount' x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathCount (x + d) (y - 1) | d <- [-1..1]]
pathCount = memoize2 pathCount'

pathSum' :: Int -> Int -> Integer
pathSum' x y
  | y == 0 = if x == 0 then 1 else 0
  | otherwise = sum [ pathSum (x + d) (y - 1) + node x y * pathCount (x + d) (y - 1)
                     | d <- [-1..1] ]
pathSum = memoize2 pathSum'

main =
  forM_ [0..n] $ \y ->
     putStrLn $ intercalate " " $ map (show . flip node y) [-n..n]
  where n = 5
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 4 6 4 2 0 0 0
0 0 4 16 40 48 40 16 4 0 0
0 8 72 352 728 944 728 352 72 8 0
16 376 4248 16608 35128 43632 35128 16608 4248 376 16
```

As you can see the algorithm the size of the numbers will get out of hands rather quickly. So the runtime is *not* O(n^2), while the number of arithmetic operations is.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will study the code intently to make sure I understand everything. One thing though, when trying to load the second part (it's in its own .hs file) I get an error on line 20 "parse error on input `import'"?

Comment: @user3625479 What's line 20? The imports should be at the top.

Comment: The imports are at the top, Line 20 is the second guard for pathSum' i.e. | otherwise = sum [ pathSum (x + d) (y-1) ...

Comment: @user3625479 I can only assume that you are doing something wrong here. Maybe you are trying to compile/load the wrong file? It should definitely not complain about an `import` being in a line where there is no `import`. If I put that code verbatim into a file, I can compile it with GHC without problems (and load it into GHCi as well)

Comment: That's what I thought was strange! It's definitely the right file. I noticed I also get an error on line 3: "Could not find module `Data.Function.Memoize'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for."

Comment: Reloading my Terminal the import error has gone, seems strange! But the other module error is still present?

Comment: @user3625479 sure, you need to install the Hackage package I linked to: `cabal install memoize`

Comment: I just tried installing memoize but I got: "11 warnings and 1 error generated.
Failed to install memoize-0.6
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
memoize-0.6 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
"

Comment: @user3625479 I don't know, this seems somewhat unrelated to the question here. Maybe you should open a new question. Probably your GHC is too old, try installing an older version of the library: `cabal install memoize-0.4` or even older, and think about upgrading GHC to at least 7.6

Comment: I have 7.6 installed?

Comment: @user3625479 OK well it *should* obviously work. You can open a new question with the exact error message (including your GHC and cabal versions and the compilation error you get while compiling. If you post the link here, I will have a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595173/trying-to-install-memoize-in-ghc-with-cabal

Comment: @user3625479 If that issue does not resolve itself, you can use [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators) instead or roll your own DP implementation with vectors. Of course you can verify the functionality without memoization, that's "just" to get polynomial runtime.

Comment: @user3625479 What's your problem? Your edit is clearly invalid and removes the relevant part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in terms of outgoing paths, when you should be thinking in terms of incoming paths. Your recursive step is currently looking for nodes from below, instead of above.

Comment: Note the bottom-up naive solution to triangular number will be highly inefficient unless the function is memoized.

Comment: So do I just reverse the signs in the otherwise guard to look from above instead of below?

Comment: Yes. Consider: When determining what the number at position (4,2) should be, what three other nodes do you look at? (Hint: NOT the third row)

Comment: I don't think the recurrence is that simple. Have you actually looked at OP's example?

Comment: I have changed the code in the otherwise guard to reflect what I have done but it is not producing the correct answers?

Comment: @user3625479 Niklas makes a good point -- this isn't a trivial variant of Pascal's Triangle. I think I see the closed form of the row-to-row recurrence, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry if this is long. I wanted to explain the step by step thought process.

To start off with, you need one crucial fact: You can represent the "answer" at each "index" by a list of paths. For all the zeros, this is `[[]]`, for your base case it is `[[1]]`, and for example, for `0,2` it is `[[6,1,1],[6,1,1],[6,1,1]]`. This may seem like some redundancy, but it simplifies things down the road. Then, extracting the answer is `head . head` if the list is non empty, or `const 0` if it is.

This is very useful because you can store the answer as a list of rows (the first row would be `'[[1]], [], [] ...`) and the results of any given row depend only on the previous row.

Secondly, this problem is symmetrical. This is pretty obvious.

The first thing we will do will mirror the definition of `fib` very closely:

```
type Path = [[Integer]]

triangle' :: [[Path]]
triangle' = ([[1]] : repeat []) : map f triangle'
```

We know this must be close to correct, since the 2nd row will depend on the first row only, the third on the 2nd only, etc. So the result will be

```
([[1]] : repeat []) : f ([[1]] : repeat []) : f ....
```

Now we just need to know what `f` is. Firstly, its type: `[Path] -> [Path]`. Quite simply, given the previous row, return the next row.

Now you may see another problem arising. Each invocation of `f` needs to know how many columns in the current row. We could actually count the length of non-null elements in the previous row, but it is simpler to pass the parameter directly, so we change `map f triangle'` to `zipWith f [1..] triangle'`, giving `f` the type `Int -> [Path] -> [Path]`.

`f` needs to handle one special case and one general case. The special case is `x=0`, in this case we simply treat the `x+1,y-1` and `x-1,y-1` recursions the same, and otherwise is identical to `gn`. Lets make two functions, `g0` and `gn` which handle these two cases.

The actually computation of `gn` is easy. We know for some `x` we need the elements `x-1, x, x+1` of the previous row. So if we drop `x-1` elements before giving the previous row to the `x`th invocation of `gn`, `gn` can just take the first 3 elements and it will have what it needs. We write this as follows:

```
f :: Int -> [Path] -> [Path]
f n ps = g0 ps : map (gn . flip drop ps) [0..n-1] ++ repeat []
```

The `repeat []` at the end should be obvious: for indices outside the triangle, the result is `0`.

Now writing `g0` and `gs` is really quite simple:

```
g0 :: [Path] -> Path 
g0 (a:b:_) =  map (s:) q 
  where 
    s = sum . concat $ q
    q = b ++ a ++ b 

gn :: [Path] -> Path 
gn (a:b:c:_) = map (s:) q 
  where 
    s = sum . concat $ q
    q = a ++ b ++ c
```

On my machine this version is about 3-4 times faster than the fastest version I could write with normal recursion and memoization.

The rest is just printing or pulling out the number you want.

```
triangle :: Int -> Int -> Integer
triangle x y = case (triangle' !! y) !! (abs x) of 
                 [] -> 0
                 xs -> head $ head xs 

triList :: Int -> Int -> Path
triList x y = (triangle' !! y) !! (abs x) 

printTri :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
printTri width height = 
  putStrLn $ unlines $ map unwords 
   [[ p $ triangle x y | x <- [-x0..x0]] | y <- [0..height]]
      where maxLen = length $ show $ triangle 0 height 
            x0 = width `div` 2
            p = printf $ "%" ++ show maxLen ++ "d "
```

Comment: Isn't that exponential time?