# "invalid preprocessing directive" when installing memoize

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, memoization

I try running:

```
cabal install memoize
```

in the Terminal but all I get is:

```
11 warnings and 1 error generated.
Failed to install memoize-0.6
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
memoize-0.6 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The 1 error is:

```
Data/Function/Memoize/TH.hs:5:6:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
        #-}
         ^
```

Comment: I have The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3 and Cabal 1.16.0 installed.

Comment: You will need to provide the actual compilation  error at least.  Not sure how to get it, have a look at the cabal docs

Comment: Is that the ExitFailure 1?

Comment: No it's not. I'm sure you have seen a Haskell compilation error before.

Comment: Are you on Mac? Here's a similar issue resolved: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1496

Here's some info on what to do on Mac: http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html